# Magnetic field vector

Tags: arduino, magnetometer

Hello i have using magnetometer lsm303agr for measuring magnetic labels x, y and z. From this labels is cumputing B vector of magnetic field.

I have calibrated my magnetometer for hard-iron compensaton.
When i plot the results in to the 2d heatmap graph where x axis and y axis are dimensions in milimeters and colour is representing magnetic vector it looks like this:

1. measurement -- walking from up to down [image]
2. measurement -- walking from up to down (except the same results and it is :D)
   [image]
3. measurement -- walking from left to the right ( except the same results but it is not)
   [image]

I tought that the 3. measurement should look like measurement which has been measured before.

Obviously when the magnetometer is rotating in one point, the vector of magnetic field is not same.

I want to know how can i get magnetic vector which will be the same in one position no mater how the magnetometer is rotated.

Thanks Mike

Comment: If your magnetometer is not rotation invariant, then you can't

Comment: I am using this magnetometer: http://www.st.com/en/mems-and-sensors/lsm303agr.html 

How can i figure if is rotation invariant (i have tried google it but without results)